# Is there a way to combine Dynamic Jasper with the newest JaspersoftStudio Version?

Tags: jaspersoft-studio, dynamic-jasper

It is no longer possible to download an older Jaspersoft Studio version. The only available option is the newest one and it is 6.21.2 at the moment. The newest Dynamic Jasper version however is 5.3.9 and it supports Jaspersoft Studio until version 6.20.4.

I tried changing the "Compiler Settings" in Window -> Preferences -> Jaspersoft Studio -> Compatibility, but this is also no longer supported. I can only use the latest Version as a compiler.

So my question is if there is a way to somehow change the Jaspersoft Studio Version to an older one so that I can use it with Dynamic Jasper?

Answer (score 0):

just google a bit, you'll find: https://www.filehorse.com/download-jaspersoft-studio/old-versions/